# How to load time into Java from Access Date/Time value?

Tags: java, date, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 dbase with Date/Time formatted values like "13/02/2013 12:33:44". If I load them into Java using Java.util.Date, the variable converts the value into "13/02/2013 00:00:00", i.e. the time-value is discarded.

How can I load date AND time from Access into Java?

thx in advance

Comment: Can you paste the code snippet?

Comment: What is the field type within Access, and what code are you using? (If you're using setDate in a PreparedStatement, that's meant to be *just* a date, not a date and time.)

Comment: Hi, the Access field type is the normal Date/Time with format "General Date". I load the data into Java with a ResultSet and then assign the Java variable of type Java.util.Date as "resultSet.getDate("date").

Comment: ResultSet rs = dbase.getResultSet("SELECT * FROM table");
while (rs.next())
 {
 variable = rs.getDate("StartDate"));
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use resultset.getTimestamp() method while reading your dates instead of resultset.getDate().